# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, dex, realm-mobile-platform

Facing this issue while I am upgrading my Android project. Upgraded following config till now:

1. Kotlin v.1.1.60 to v.1.2.41
2. along with above change I added plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and replaced `annotationProcessor` to `kapt`
3. Upgraded dependency `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` to `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` as I got the warning that `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` was deprecated for new Kotlin version

Uptill now, my project isworking i.e. getting compiled and APK is getting generated. Now I made following changes:

1. Upgraded Realm from v.2.2.2 to v.5.1.0
2. At this stage, my project was not getting compiled. For classes such as `Realm`, `RealmResults` I was getting 'unresolved reference'. Then I added below code in application's build.gradle

   realm {
   syncEnabled = true
   }

Now 'unresolved reference' is resolved but I am getting above error mentioned in the question.

```
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/Users/macusername/.android/build-cache/1356d0bbf59bd3c075dd3c13537428b6de3f0678/output/jars/classes.jar' to '/Users/macusername/AndroidProjects/project-name/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/flavour-name/debugSIT/folders/1000/10/classes_3ca2264d84fdd4905c647b112b0d3c683ba517e0'
```

Comment: u got any soultion

Comment: @lisha It was a version compatibility issue. I was using Realm v.5.1.0 with latest gradle 3.1 and Kotlin. Solution is to downgrade gradle or upgrade realm. Also Kotlin supports Realm uptill v.4.3.

Comment: @lisha Let me know what solution you got and also your problem.